# Is a TLS negotiation failure error proof that connectivity exists?

Tags: ssl, iis, networking

We are attempting to allow a client to access one of our QA environments.  They are seeing the following error in IE:

**This page can't be displayed**
*Turn on TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1, and TLS 1.2 in Advanced settings and try connecting to https://oursite.com again.  if this error persists, it is possible that this site uses an unsupported protocol or cipher suite such as RC4 (link for the details), which is not considered secure.  Pelase contact your site administrator.*

I am not asking stackoverflow users to solve this problem.

I am asking the following very specific question:

Because we are seeing this error, **does this prove that connectivity exists, i.e. our firewall is letting them through?**  I am thinking if they were blocked at the firewall they would simply get a timeout or perhaps a 403 or 500 error.  since they are getting so far as to be able to see what TLS protocols are supported on the web server, I infer that they must be able to communicate with it on OSI levels 1-4.  Am I correct?  (I need to know whether to engage the networking team, which runs the firewalls, or to engage the application support team, which sets up the TLS configuration).

Note that SSL terminates on our IIS web server (we don't have SSL offloading).

Unfortunately we have port 80 blocked so we can only test on 443; otherwise I would suggest using http access to help isolate the problem.

Comment: If your site is accessible from the internet, you can test its SSL/TLS support from https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/  Also, tools such as `telnet` can be used to test basic TCP connectivity:  `telnet oursite.com 443` will test basic TCP connectivity from the host it's run on to port 443 on `oursite.com`.

Answer (score 0):

> ... if they were blocked at the firewall they would simply get a timeout or perhaps a 403 or 500 error.

In order to send back a 403 or 500 error the firewall must have successfully done the SSL handshake with the client because the HTTP response (which includes the status code, i.e. 403, 500..) will only be sent inside the encrypted connection. There is no way to return a 403 or 500 inside the SSL handshake already.

Typical behavior with a firewall in between would be a timeout (firewalls drops packet) or more likely a connection reset or close (firewall resets or closes the connection). With a simple packet filter firewall it will usually block the TCP connection already, resulting in connection refused. But a firewall using DPI might actually let the TCP connection establish and only block after it gets actual data based on the content of this payload (i.e. application detection).

The last case might  result in the error you see. But exactly the same behavior can be seen if there is a problem on the server side where the server simply closes or resets the connection. Some TLS stacks show such behavior (instead of sending back a TLS alert) when they cannot find a shared protocol version or cipher.  Insofar you can neither conclude from this error message that the firewall is blocking the connection nor can you conclude that the server is causing the error.